# Live streaming H.264 in DirectShow

Tags: http, directshow, h.264, live-streaming

Does anyone know which filters in DirectShow I have to use in order to stream H.264 LIVE stream over http?
(especially what kind of source filter I have to use)

Any code suggestion will be helpful.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you want to receive H.264 live stream over some real time protocol tunnelled through HTTP, or do you want to have a filter that will transmit (send) a stream through HTTP to the internet?

Comment: @Ralf sir thanks for the rtsp source filter but how to use it in direct show please tell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean HTTP tunneling or the chunk-based methods of apple (MPEG-TS) and MicroSoft (MP4) ?

If you are looking for a tunneling solution, the following might be helpful:

One (typical) option is to use an RTSP source filter. However there is no stock RTSP source filter in windows. You can write your own or try to use one of the following: 
http://rtpstream.com/downloads.shtml
I have never used it so can't say how well it works, I do remember seeing the HTTP tunneling option though.

I have also made an example one available at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/) if you are looking for one with source code. It uses the [live555](http://www.live555.com) library for RTSP/RTP/RTCP. It was aimed at streaming some audio formats and I only *recently* started playing around with adding H.264 support to it. I managed to stream the example H.264 files available from live555. Perhaps it could be helpful in getting started. Live555 does support HTTP tunneling, but you would have to modify the filter source code to get it right.

Comment: Yes, RTSP Source Filter from rtpstream.com is good for all kinds of RTP transport including HTTP tunnelling. But it has a limit of 32 filter instances running... that only sux.

Comment: @Ralf sir thanks for the rtsp source filter but how to use it in direct show please tell and where can we find its source i mean of RTSP source filter

Comment: @Cipi sir how to use RTSP source filter in an application please tell

Comment: @Dany You can download the source at http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/develop?source=navbar You would use it like any other DirectShow filter, load it using it's GUID, or further, you can register the source filter for the rtsp protocol, see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377513(v=vs.85).aspx . Doing so would e.g. allow you to use WMP

Comment: @Ralf sir i wan to use RTSP Source filter in the GMF bridge given on the following link http://www.gdcl.co.uk/gmfbridge/   please guide how to use it

Comment: @Ralf Sir can you also give me some sample link which i can debug and build the filter which take the rtsp streaming from network through socket connection and plays that stream in GMF bridge

Answer (score 0):

[Www.3ivx.com](http://Www.3ivx.com/) makes a DirectShow source filter which supports RTSP and Apple style HTTP Live Streaming

We're currently using it in another project