# Is there a DirectShow Filter for an RTP compatible IP camera?

Tags: filter, directshow, rtp, ip-camera

Does there exist a DirectShow filter that takes in a video stream from the network in RTP format? The purpose is to use the video stream of an IP camera in my application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard filter. Third party filters exist (mostly commercial) and you might want to check with camera vendor if they can provide you with such filter, at least compatible with their products, e.g. as a part of complementary SDK.

See:

- [Live streaming H.264 in DirectShow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6450463/live-streaming-h-264-in-directshow)
- [RTSP/RTP Source filter (8/16 bit PCM AMR MP3, H264)](http://sourceforge.net/projects/videoprocessing/files/DirectShow/DirectShowFilters/RTSP%20Source%20Filter%20%28audio%29/)

Comment: Thanks, 2nd link is great ... For any others who want to use it: it's easy to test with this RTSP server application from live555: http://www.live555.com/mediaServer/